# file_get_contents not working for my domain

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I tried to parse a website's html using file_get_contents().

I ran the code from my website.

It worked fine at first.But suddenly this error appeared:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.***.com/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

I tried other websites and it works fine.I ran the code from my other website and it works fine.

So I searched here and used the cURL code:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.***.com/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

But it just returns a blank page.

Looks like the website I tried to get contents blocked or blacklisted my website domain or something.

Do I have a way out of this ??

Comment: What is the link of the website?

Comment: @Antony http://www.azlyrics.com/

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/4Kt71m

Answer (score 3):

You could try to figure out why your connection is being blocked:

- IP based: they blocked your server.
- User Agent based: send a user agent that identifies you as a bot.
- If they don't like your bot user agent pretend to be someone else's bot, like Google (*evil*)
- If they block bots, send a user agent that looks like a browser (*evil*)
- Some other parameter that identifies a browser vs a script.

Answer (score 1):

your server cannot get to the other server

possibly dns issues, misspelling or the other server has blocked your ip..

what does curl_error() says?

BTW, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT 2 seconds is usually quite small